# Expressing this angle in terms of other angles

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I want to express $\theta$ in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (or their tangents or other trig functions), but have no idea how to do so. Can someone please clarify? I just don't see the needed relations.

[image]

Comment: $$\theta =\pi-(\pi-(\alpha+\beta))=\alpha+\beta.$$ Angles on a line add to $\pi$, angles in a triangle add to $\pi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $D$ be the other endpoint of the line marked $b$, and let $\gamma = \text{m} \angle ADB$. Obviously $\theta + \gamma = \pi$, because $\theta$ and $\gamma$ add up to one side of the a straight line (the infinite line $AD$, namely). What do you know about $\alpha + \beta + \gamma$?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

That is a general and very know result called **External Angle Theorem**:

$$\angle A+\angle B+\angle C=180°\to\alpha+\beta+\angle C=180° \quad (1)$$

and also

$$\angle C+\theta=180° \to \angle C=180°-\theta\quad (2)$$

By $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get

$$\theta=\alpha +\beta$$

Answer (score 1):

Let E be the end point of line marked as b.

And $\angle BEC = y$

Then in $\triangle BEC$

$y + \alpha + 90 = 180$

$y + \alpha = 90$

$y = 90 - \alpha$

Let $\angle AEC = z$

Then in $\triangle AEC$

$z + 90 + \beta = 180$

$z + \beta = 90$

$z = 90 - \beta$

Also,

$\theta + y + z = 180$

Putting the values of $y$ and $z$ from above equations,

$\theta + 90 - \alpha + 90 - \beta = 180$

$\theta = \alpha + \beta$

Answer (score 0):

When a side of triangle is produced, external angle $ \theta $ so formed equals  sum of internal angles $ \alpha , \beta. $